# If $ \int^\infty_0 f(x)dx$ is not finite then at least one of $ \int^\infty_0 f(x)g(x)dx$ and $ \int^\infty_0 \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$ is not finite.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f, g : [0, +∞) \to (0, +∞)$ be continuous functions and suppose that the improper integral
$ \int^\infty_0 f(x)dx$ is not finite.

Show that at least one of the improper integrals:
$$\displaystyle  \int^\infty_0 f(x)g(x)dx$$
$$ \displaystyle\int^\infty_0 \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$$
is not finite.

It feels intuitive and similar to comparison theorem, however here we don't know if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for $(x \geq a)$ and that makes me confused.

Comment: Use [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2). $\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\right)\geq\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}\sqrt{\frac{f((x)}{g(x)}}dx$

Comment: Another method: use the fact that for all $x>0$, $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$.